# UNION ALL or CONCATENATE Datasets in BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I'm working with the BigQuery console and need to make a union from 12 diferent datasets but the information is the same, only change de dataset_id because the date range is the same for all.

I try to put the `union all` function at the end of the first query and next the other query, but not works.

```
Error: SELECT list expression references hits.contentgroup.contentgroup2 which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:3]
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT
  hits.contentgroup.contentgroup2 CampaignGrouping,
  custd.value member_PK,
  'Web' Canal,
  'ES' AS country_id,
  SUM(hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2) VistasUnicas
FROM
  `id_project.11773102.ga_sessions*`,
  UNNEST(customdimensions) custd,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-04-25') AND TIMESTAMP('2017-04-30')
  AND custd.index=30
  and hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2 <> '(not set)'
  AND custd.value <> 'null'
  AND hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  hits.contentgroup.contentgroup2 CampaignGrouping,
  custd.value member_PK,
  'Web' Canal,
  'ES' AS country_id,
  SUM(hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2) VistasUnicas
FROM
  `id_project.11773102.ga_sessions*`,
  UNNEST(customdimensions) custd,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-04-25') AND TIMESTAMP('2017-04-30')
  AND custd.index=30
  and hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2 <> '(not set)'
  AND custd.value <> 'null'
  AND hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2 IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY
  1, 2
ORDER BY 5 ASC
```

Thanks.

Comment: What, if any, error are you getting. Explain "not works" - IOW, what isn't working.

Comment: sorry @SloanThrasher i included at the question now,

Comment: So, the error message seems to be pretty clear. Where does hits.contentgroup.contentgroup2 come from?

Comment: Came from the table thta I'm declared at the query. When i run the query without the union all, runs!
I don't know why happens this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` with the first query in the union, e.g.:

```
SELECT
  hits.contentgroup.contentgroup2 CampaignGrouping,
  custd.value member_PK,
  'Web' Canal,
  'ES' AS country_id,
  SUM(hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2) VistasUnicas
FROM
  `bigquery-aaaaa-162814.11773102.ga_sessions*`,
  UNNEST(customdimensions) custd,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-04-25') AND TIMESTAMP('2017-04-30')
  AND custd.index=30
  and hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2 <> '(not set)'
  AND custd.value <> 'null'
  AND hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
```

As a concrete example of `UNION ALL` with `GROUP BY`:

```
#standardSQL
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'bar' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'foo'
)
SELECT x, STRING_AGG(y, ',') AS y
FROM T
GROUP BY x
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(x), y
FROM T
GROUP BY y;
```